# React: performance gains of keys

Tags: javascript, html, performance, reactjs, jsx

Do I need to add keys on parts like

```
<div>
   <div key="upper">
      ...
   </div>
   <div key="lower">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

React doesn't complain about missing keys, since those `div`s  don't come from arrays, but I wondered if the improve performance? 
I'd rather not have them for sake of less code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they do not improve performance. The keys in Arrays are there so that React can assume the whole element to be unchanged as long as the key didn't change. For example, if you change the array, but keep some of the old values, React will probably try to reuse some of the old elements.

Comment: Any performance gains would only be relevant in case of large lists, where - say - you delete first item. With keys, react is smart enough to reuse items (remove the first item, instead of changing content of new item 1 to content of old item 2 etc.). When doing this manually (instead of array), it is not likely your list will become long enough for keys to make any difference.